# Data from table1 doesn't move to table2

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have this button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-md" title="moure a Acollits"><a href="?moureAc_id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" onclick="return confirm('Estàs segur que vols moure aquest gat a Acollits?')">Acollit</a></button>
```

And when I click on it and confirm, I want it to delete table1 data for this specific ID and move it to table2. Currently it deletes the data fine but doesn't move it to the second table so I don't know what I'm doing wrong!

Code:

```
if(isset($_GET['moureAc_id'])){
    $prepIexec = $conn->prepare('SELECT foto FROM TaulaGats WHERE id =:uid');
    $prepIexec->execute(array(':uid'=>$_GET['moureAc_id']));
    $imatgeRow = $prepIexec->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    unlink("imatges/".$imatgeRow['foto']);

    $eliminar = $conn->prepare('DELETE FROM TaulaGats WHERE id =:uid');
    $eliminar->bindParam(':uid', $_GET['moureAc_id']);
    $eliminar->execute();

    $moure = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO TaulaGatsA (nom, sexe, edat, foto) SELECT nom, sexe, edat, foto FROM TaulaGats WHERE id = :uid');
    $moure->bindParam(':uid', $_GET['moureAc_id']);
    $moure->execute();

    header("Location: index.php");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're deleting the data before moving it. Execute the INSERT statement, then the DELETE statement.